# Jquery works in firebug but not in page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm quite new to JQuery programming and need a bit of help!

I have a ASP.NET Pivot Table and i the cells of that table there a #re v arious values 1, 2, 3 or 4. Whichever value is selected turns the cell to one of four colours. Now the code works in firebug but does not work, when i put it in tags in my page header.

what am i doing wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../../Scripts/jquery-1.6.1.min.js">



    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(".myGridView1 tr").each(function () {



            $("td").filter(function () { return $.text([this]) == '1'; }).css('background', 'green');

            $("td").filter(function () { return $.text([this]) == '2'; }).css('background', 'orange');

            $("td").filter(function () { return $.text([this]) == '3'; }).css('background', 'red');

            $("td").filter(function () { return $.text([this]) == '4'; }).css('background', 'blue');

        });

    });



</script>
```

Comment: I would suggest you add a class to the td based on that value if you can (on server side).. ie `<td class="1">...</td>` Then just style it in your css as you want..

Comment: @lucuma, you can't have classes starting with a number according to the CSS specifications.

Comment: I normally wouldn't do that since it isn't descriptive and you are of course correct.. My answer was updated below.

Comment: I would look at your `each()` loop as well.  It isn't doing anything other than making your code very inefficient.  See my answer for how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot include an external script in the same tag that contains your page code.  It needs to be a separate, empty tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
   // my script
</script>
```

**In addition, some notes:**

The `.each()` function doesn't do anything in your code, except run the filter functions too many times.  For each `tr`, you are looking at **every** `td`, not just the ones in the current row.  If you take out the `.each()`, the code still works:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/dgswh/

Secondly, instead of filtering, just add the function to your `.css()` call:

```
var colors = {'1': 'green', '2': 'orange', '3': 'red', '4': 'blue' };

$("td").css('background-color', function(index, value) {
    var txt = $(this).text();
    if(colors.hasOwnProperty(txt)) {
        return colors[txt];
    }
    return value;
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/dgswh/2/

This reduces your code to a single call, instead of 4 (and it only runs once for each `td`).  If you want to limit it to just that table, change the selector:

```
$(".myGridView1 td").css('background-color', function(index, value) { ... });
```

**Follow up**

To remove the text from the `td` after changing the color, you can do this:

```
$("td").css('background-color', function(index, value) {
    var txt = $(this).text();
    $(this).text("");  // ADD THIS LINE
    if(colors.hasOwnProperty(txt)) {
        return colors[txt];
    }
    return value;
});
```

If you only want to remove the text of `td`s that match, move the line:

```
$("td").css('background-color', function(index, value) {
    var txt = $(this).text();
    if(colors.hasOwnProperty(txt)) {
        $(this).text("");  // MOVE TO HERE
        return colors[txt];
    }
    return value;
});
```

It is important to note that without some styling, if you empty a table cell, it may collapse to zero width or if all cells on a row are empty, the row may collapse to zero height.  If this is the case, either add `min-height` and `min-width` definitions for `td` in your CSS, or change `$(this).text("")` to `$(this).html('&nbsp;')`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/dgswh/5/

If you want to retain the number, but not have it be visible, you can wrap the contents of the `td` with a hidden or invisible `div`:

```
$(this).wrapInner("<div style='visibility:hidden'>");
```

Or:

```
$(this).wrapInner("<div style='display:none'>");
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/dgswh/6/

Comment: Thanks a lot. This code works great.  If I have another question regatding your script can I ask it here or do I have to open a new thread?

Comment: You can generally ask a follow up question in the comments (here).  But, it is not considered good practice to change the original question, or to ask a new, involved question as a comment.  What's your question?

Comment: Thats great! So in keeping with the same thread, from the code you've supplied above how could you remove the visibility of the actual value number from the td so that its only the colour on view?

Comment: You want to update the color and then remove the text from the `td`?  See my edit in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Each script needs its own tag, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../../Scripts/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".myGridView1 tr").each(function() {
        $("td").filter(function() {
            return $.text([this]) == '1';
        }).css('background', 'green');

        $("td").filter(function() {
            return $.text([this]) == '2';
        }).css('background', 'orange');

        $("td").filter(function() {
            return $.text([this]) == '3';
        }).css('background', 'red');

        $("td").filter(function() {
            return $.text([this]) == '4';
        }).css('background', 'blue');

    });
});​
</script>
```

The reason being is the Javascript is loaded into the html at the specified tag (if you've specified a URL) and will, to the best of my knowledge, overwrite what's inside the script tag currently. So if you've got anything inside a `<script>` tag with a URL set, it will be overridden and thus not execute.

Also, it's Javascript programming, not jQuery programming. jQuery is a library to be used with Javascript.

Comment: Please format and mention that you have added the missing `<script>` tags

Comment: @Vega: Just did. I was just "getting my answer out there", you know? :)

Comment: hahaha I know, +1 from me :) Also Can you point out that he can use `.each` and use `$(this).text() == '..'` and update css accordingly.

Comment: The incorrect script include would definitely cause an issue.. I sure hope the issue was more complex than that (man, I didn't even notice that).

Answer (score 2):

The contents of a `script` are ignored if the `src` attribute is present.  In other words, you need two `script` tags: one to include jQuery, and the other for your code.  You're also doing a lot more work than you need to:

```
$(function () {
   $(".myGridView1 tr td:contains(1)").css('background', 'green');
...
});
```

You can probably consolidate it even further.  Just a few notes:

`$.text([this])` is not much different than `$(this).text()` .. the latter is preferred.

Your `.each` is pointless, because the `$("td")` selector operates on the entire document.  If you really wanted to use the `.each` selector as the context, you could do `$("td", this)`.  I don't think it's necessary to even use `.each`, though.  It's just an extra function call.

Finally, you can use the `:contains` selector for what you're trying to do with the `.filter`.  I don't see much of a reason to ever use `.filter` as opposed to selectors unless the `.filter` method is extremely complicated or you want to use it for chaining.

Comment: +1 for detailed explanation. Would be really nice if you can point him to jQuery docs as well.

Comment: The docs in general are at http://api.jquery.com .. it's pretty easy to search for methods.  You can look at selectors, `:contains`, and `.filter` as those are the most relevant here.

Comment: A little bit more about the `script` tag (including the root of your problem: http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20100624/scripting-1.html#script

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we aren't talking about an incorrect script tag, here is a solution:

css:

```
.td1 {background-color:green}
.td2 {background-color:orange}
etc



$(".myGridView1 td").each(function() {
   $(this).addClass('td' + $(this).text());

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../../Scripts/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function(){

        $(".myGridView1 td").each(function () {

            var that = $(this)

            switch( that.text() ){

                  case '1': that.css('background', 'green');
                  break;

                  case '2': that.css('background', 'orange');
                  break;

                  case '3': that.css('background', 'red');
                  break;

                  case '4': that.css('background', 'blue');
                  break;
            } 

        });

    });
</script>
```

Just my 2 cents. You should avoid making new jQuery objects (less `$` the better) and filter is pretty inefficient too. This way each jQuery object is created once, and each function runs once.